# Is there any function that generate escaped sql query for AWS RDS Data API?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I am using RDS client of AWS Data API to insert data into AuroraDB through a lambda function.
I have included all parameters into the query, so the query is not escaped.
I know the parameterized query prevents SQL injection, but I cannot upgrade all my code.
So I just want to escape the parameters while making the query.
Is there any method that the RDS client provides for escaping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no boto3 method (via the RDS client or otherwise) to achieve this that I am aware of. There are however ways of achieving an escaped string in python by using native string replace calls, raw strings, etc.